# Mysql group limited data from table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a account table i want to take all the recipient names who get more or equal to 1024 amount within 3 biggest transaction.

I am attaching a image to demonstrate data in table, the result of these will be two rows with recipient name nutan and vicky

[image]

--

```
select recipient from accounts group by recipient having sum(amount) >= 1024 and count(*) <=3
```

Comment: This will require multiple subqueries, 1] you will have to use rownumber to limit the top 3 records for each name 2] then sum the amount with group by with having clause to check for sum(amount) >= 1024 and then 3] select the recipient column only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution feeling like superhero now.

```
set @num=1,@recp:='';
select 
@recp:=recipient as recipient
from 
(select recipient,amount from accounts order by recipient,amount desc) as accounts
where (@num:=if(@recp=recipient,@num+1,1))<4
group by recipient
having sum(amount)>=1024
order by recipient,amount desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the top three transactions.  Possibly the simplest method is to use variables:

```
select recipient
from (select a.*,
             (@rn := if(@r = recipient, @rn + 1,
                        if(@rn := recipient, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from accounts a cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @r := '') params
      order by recipient, amount desc
     ) a
where rn <= 3
group by recipient
having sum(amount) >= 1024;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordan actually, it is giving karan also in recipient list which is not right

Comment: This should only be returning recipients where the three largest amounts exceed 1024 (my understanding of the question).  If you set up an example on SQL Fiddle, I can look at it.